# In lightning, Service console can I display buttons in the highlight panel based on custom field like if field is not empty?

Tags: lightning

In lightning, Service console can I display buttons in the highlight panel based on the custom field like only if the field is not empty display change owner button.

Answer (score 1):

Developer console is for developing the code so not clear about your question. Highlight Panel is Out of the box component and only fields can be shown there detail can be found [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_compact_layouts)
For creating button see example [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_buttons_links)

To your answer no we can not control the visibility of button based on a field value in the satandard button section. You may create a custom component of buttons and expose it in flexi page to do that. Hope this answer your question.

Comment: Sorry Typing mistake, it's Service Console.

Comment: The answer is still same if you put buttons or action on page layouts it will be always visible to control visibility in a custom way you need a custom component